# Command to list the number of mappers and reducers in HADOOP 2.x

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Is there any hadoop/yarn commands to list the number of mapper/reducers/slots used by the job dynamically

Comment: If there is, these are documented. Did you do any research?

Comment: tried a lot in documentation. I could find some configuration files which is having the number of mappers/reducers with memory information in hadoop 1. But not in hadoop-2. Yarn configuration list only the memory information about mappers/reducers.

Answer (score 0):

YARN deals with containers and memory not Mappers and Reducers.

In order to get your information you probably need a 2 step approach.  Run the YARN [Resource Manager Cluster Application API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_API) to get the Application Master URL.

Then run the [Mapreduce Application Master Info API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapredAppMasterRest.html) against the AM URL to get the number of running mappers and reducers.

Comment: Thanks @tk421. It would be good to get the info using some CLI commands.